# Unable to get IntelliJ to recognize proto compiled Java class files

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, protobuf-c

We have a build.xml in our project, but IntelliJ is unable to import from it. I get a:

```
Cannot import anything from <path_to>/build.xml file.
```

On Eclipse I can do a:

```
File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into workspace.
```

and chose top-level folder. I did the same in IJ. The project imported and indexed fine, I can do a search for any class. However, it does not recognize protobuf compiled class files. I installed the proto plugin, so it syntax highlights my .proto files, but still doesn't realize that there's a compiled class output that it needs to refer to. Do I need to do something special to get it to recognize those files?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

since this is pretty much the only place I could find an *exact* description for the issue I was facing with Idea, I'm replying even if it's an old question.

It turns out that if the `.java` file that's generated by the protocol buffers compiler is larger than 2.5MB (default setting), Idea ignores it altogether. Even if there is a `.class` file, even if compile/make succeed, even if you build your project just fine with Maven.

To fix that, simply edit your `idea.properties` file (it's inside the `bin` folder in your Idea installation folder), and either comment out this setting, or set it to something larger than your generated `.java` file (in my case, I set it to `15000`, as my generated file is currently about 8MB in size):

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Maximum file size (kilobytes) IDE should provide code assistance for.
# The larger file is the slower its editor works and higher overall system memory requirements are
# if code assistance is enabled. Remove this property or set to very large number if you need
# code assistance for any files available regardless their size.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=2500
```

**Note**: at least on Linux, where the default update policy seems to be "overwrite the old Idea folder with what you just downloaded", this change must be applied after every update/upgrade.

Comment: Also works for me, but I still find that documentation confusing. I don't *want* to open the file in the editor and also don't want code assistance for it. Quite the contrary I want to avoid code assistance if I happen to open the file accidentely in idea, in order not to crash/block it. Isn't there any way to configure the limit for compilation independent of the limit for code assistance in the editor?

Comment: spent hours trying to figure this out, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

An extension to Michele's answer,

You can do this directly from your IntelliJ.

In macOS, when Intellij is unable to recognize proto compiled Java class files,

From the Help menu ---> select Edit Custom Properties. It might ask you to create `idea.properties` file under

```
$HOME//Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.1/
```

create property idea.max.intellisense.filesize=2500 and set the value to accommodate your big fat proto compiled file for IntelliJ to recognize.

Comment: There is `bin` folder in macos
press right click on Idea in Application folder and select `Show package content`